# change value in Pandas dataframe after filtering

Tags: python, filter, pandas, dataframe

I want to do something in a Pandas dataframe like below:

1. select rows that column `status` contains the phrase `HOLD` or `RECALL`
2. change the value of `recall_hold` for these rows from `FALSE` to `TRUE`

I used the code as below but failed:

```
book_status_df['recall_hold'] = 'FALSE'
book_status_df.loc[book_status_df.status.str.contains('HOLD|RECALL')]['recall_hold'] = 'TRUE'
book_status_df[book_status_df['recall_hold']=='TRUE']
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You are performing chain indexing, try changing your middle line to this: `book_status_df.loc[book_status_df.status.str.contains('HOLD|RECALL'),'recall_hold'] = 'TRUE'`

Comment: See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) on the rules and correct usage